# Gitlab-ci multiple images, before_script per stage and installing dependency to image

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have some questions related to gitlab-ci

1. How can I use more than one image? Maybe one image per stage or depend on job name?

> ```
> ####  How use one image for JobA1 and JobA2  
>
> JobA1:
>     stage: Test
>     script:
>         - ansible-playbook testa1.yml
>
> JobA2:
>     stage: Test
>     script:
>         - ansible-playbook testa2.yml
>
> ####  How use other image to JobB1 and JobB2  
>
> JobB1:
>     stage: Test
>     script:
>         - ansible-playbook testa1.yml
>
> JobB2:
>     stage: Test
>     script:
>         - ansible-playbook testa2.yml
> ```

2. How can I use before_script depends on stage?
3. How can I install dependency to image? I tried do it like that

> ```
> before_script:
> - apt update
> - apt install software-properties-common
> - apt-add-repository --yes --update ppa:ansible/ansible
> - apt install ansible
> ```

I see in the log that the commands from before_script will execute, but when installing ansible the installation must be confirmed - how can I do it? Alternatively, is there a better way to install ansible to the image?

> ```
> 0 upgraded, 73 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
> Need to get 24.8 MB of archives.
> After this operation, 112 MB of additional disk space will be used.
> Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out that I need a docker image that has ansible installed. There were no such in dockerhub so I created mine where Ansible and Molecule are installed. You can use :)

[Ubuntu:18.04 image](https://hub.docker.com/r/belluu/ubuntu-ansible)

[Debian:10 image](https://hub.docker.com/r/belluu/debian-ansible)

[CentOS:8 image](https://hub.docker.com/r/belluu/centos-ansible)